# Creating a WaveStream from PCM samples

Tags: c#, audio, naudio

I checked NAudio and its `WaveStream` related classes, but I couldn't find a built in way to create a `WaveStream` based on PCM samples that I provide.

Ideally I would like to do something like this:

```
byte[] samples = ...
WaveFormat waveFormat = new WaveFormat(audioSampleRate, 
                                       audioBitsPerSample,
                                       audioChannels);
WaveStream waveStream = CreateWaveStreamfromSamples(waveFormat,
                                                    samples);
```

**Is there a way to do this using NAudio?**

**Edit** after clarification from Hans, Mark (thanks for the feedback):

I needed a stream that I could pass to `SoundPlayer.Play`, this doesn't fit well with `WaveStream`. In my project I ended up implementing the following class which takes samples and a `WaveFormat` and can be played back by `SoundPlayer`.

```
public class MemoryWaveStream : Stream
{
    public override bool CanSeek { get { return false; } }
    public override bool CanWrite { get { return false; } }
    public override bool CanRead { get { return true; } }
    public override long Length { get { return _waveStream.Length; } }
    public override long Position { get { return _waveStream.Position; } set { _waveStream.Position = value; } }

    private MemoryStream _waveStream;

    public MemoryWaveStream(byte[] sampleData, WaveFormat waveFormat)
    {
        _waveStream = new MemoryStream();
        BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(_waveStream);
        bw.Write(new char[4] { 'R', 'I', 'F', 'F' });

        int length = 36 + sampleData.Length;
        bw.Write(length);

        bw.Write(new char[8] { 'W', 'A', 'V', 'E', 'f', 'm', 't', ' ' });

        waveFormat.Serialize(bw);
        bw.Write(new char[4] { 'd', 'a', 't', 'a' });
        bw.Write(sampleData.Length);
        bw.Write(sampleData, 0, sampleData.Length);
        _waveStream.Position = 0;
    }

    public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        return _waveStream.Read(buffer, offset, count);
    }

    public override void Flush()
    {
        _waveStream.Flush();
    }

    public override long Seek(long offset, SeekOrigin origin)
    {
        return _waveStream.Seek(offset, origin);
    }

    public override void SetLength(long value)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for supplying the custom class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, nothing like it.  You can however create your own.  The wave\wavestream\wavefilereader.cs source code file is probably best to get started with.  Bunch of stuff you can strip from it, replace the waveStream by a properly initialized MemoryStream.

Comment: yea I did my own (implementing Stream derived class using a MemoryStream internally and just slapping on a Wave header), but would have preferred something built-in instead of re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: I did submit it for a patch - I don't know whether this class is useful for the project as a whole, we'll see ;-)

Comment: @BrokenGlass - WaveStreams should not return Wave headers from their Read method - only audio. The `WaveFormat` is used by the `WaveFileWriter` when writing to a WAV file.

Comment: @Mark - my mistake. I needed a stream that was playable by SoundPlayer, so deriving from WaveStream is probably not the right choice. I'll post what I ended up with in an edit.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a class that you can pass a `MemoryStream` based on your byte array into if you want. I'll probably include something like this in NAudio 1.4 as I get a lot of support requests about how to do this.

```
public class RawSourceWaveStream : WaveStream
{
    private Stream sourceStream;
    private WaveFormat waveFormat;

    public RawSourceWaveStream(Stream sourceStream, WaveFormat waveFormat)
    {
        this.sourceStream = sourceStream;
        this.waveFormat = waveFormat;
    }

    public override WaveFormat WaveFormat
    {
        get { return this.waveFormat; }
    }

    public override long Length
    {
        get { return this.sourceStream.Length; }
    }

    public override long Position
    {
        get
        {
            return this.sourceStream.Position;
        }
        set
        {
            this.sourceStream.Position = value;
        }
    }

    public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        return sourceStream.Read(buffer, offset, count);
    }
}
```